# Proving context free language membership is $P$ complete with respect to log-space reductions

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, automata, solution-verification

This is exercise from *Introduction to Automata theory, Languages and Computation, by Hopcrof, Ullman* (first edition). I found example of polynomial reduction to some problems in logic, or graph theory, but I'm interested is it possible to prove this using fact that problem if CFG G is empty is $P$ complete with respect to log-space reductions? (let $L_{CFE}$ be set of all context free empty languages)

Is this ok or I need something more:

> Checking if $x\in L$ is same as checking if $L^\mathsf{c}\cap\{x\}$ is empty. Class $\cal{P}$ is closed on complement and intersection so $L^\mathsf{c}\cap\{x\}$ is in $\cal{P}$. For reduction we construct TM $M$  with just on stage: for input $x$ check if $L^\mathsf{c}\cap\{x\}$ is empty, and if it is return $L^\mathsf{c}\cap\{x\}$ and accept, else return$\{x\}$ and decline.
>
> This machine accepts only if result is empty language. But I'm not sure if this is log-space reduction and how to prove it if it is?

Comment: I _think_ your solution assumes that the complement of a context-free language is context-free (in your use of $L^c$).  However, the complement of a context-free language may not be context-free

Comment: Yes you are right... :/ I'm not sure how to prove it then...

Comment: to be perfectly honest, I'm not exactly certain what you are trying to prove. Are you trying to show that the language $\{ \langle w , L \rangle : L\text{ is CGL and }x \in L \}$ is LOGSPACE-reducible to $\{ G : G\text{ is a CFG and }L(G) = \varnothing \}$?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: yes =)! and then conclude that the first language is P-complete since second is